# Adding a link to callout ellipsis list?

Tags: callouts

for document files i would like to add a link ("my custom link") into the callout ellipsis list.

Document ...(Edit, Share, Follow, ...(View Properties, Edit Properties, "my custom link")).

I found a lot of info on hover callouts but nothing about adding to the ellipsis list. 
(ex: view properties).  I just want to add a link/option inside this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 pages that will help answer this...

http://blog.milanchauhan.com/2013/08/custom-item-menu-action-in-document.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163954%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)